# How to determine the most contributing features for a Linear SVM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to code the most important features for a linear svm in sklearn, and I found some lines online already, but when applying it to my code it returns an error. What should I do?

My code:

```
class SVMSentiment(Base):
    """Predict sentiment scores using a linear Support Vector Machine (SVM).
    Uses a sklearn pipeline.
    """
    def __init__(self, model_file: str=None) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        # pip install sklearn
        from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer, TfidfVectorizer
        from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
        from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC
        from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


        self.pipeline = Pipeline(
            [
                #('vect', CountVectorizer()),
               # ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
                ('clf', LinearSVC( loss='hinge'
   


                )),
            ]
        )



    def predict(self, train_file: str, test_file: str, lower_case: bool) -> pd.DataFrame:
        "Train model using sklearn pipeline"
        from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
        from sklearn.svm import SVC
        from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
        from sklearn import svm
        from sklearn import preprocessing
        from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
        from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
        from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
        train_df = self.read_data(train_file, lower_case)



        learner = self.pipeline.fit(train_df['text'], train_df['truth'])
        # Fit the learner to the test data
        test_df = self.read_data(test_file, lower_case)

        test_df['pred'] = learner.predict(test_df['text'])
      
        return test_df

    def f_importances(coef, names):
    

        imp = coef
        imp, names = zip(*sorted(zip(imp, names)))
        plt.barh(range(len(names)), imp, align='center')
        plt.yticks(range(len(names)), names)
        plt.show()



    features_names = [train_df['text'], train_df['truth']]
    learner = self.pipeline.fit(train_df['text'], train_df['truth'])
    print(f_importances(self.pipeline.coef_, features_names))
```

The error says:

```
NameError: name 'train_df' is not defined
```

But I already defined train_df, so I don't understand how I should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You only defined variable *train_df* inside the function *predict()* in your class, that means it only exists there for now. Since you did not return it anywhere and it is not a global variable, you cannot just access it outside of that class.

To access the variable *train_df*, you need to define this variable outside of the class, or return it from the class before you call it here:

```
...
features_names = [train_df['text'], train_df['truth']]
...
```